# SNMP Trap and Alarm Severity

Tags: cisco, snmp

I have an issue over SNMP trap. I am using Cisco's private MIB. There I can use separate OID for alarm severity and it holds the values as follows.

- MajorLow = 0
- MinorLow = 1
- Nominal = 2
- MinorHigh = 3
- MajorHigh = 4

Using these states I am showing the alarm severity of the device in my NMS.

But when the device generates trap, it sends the alarm severity with only two states (MAJOR = 1 or MINOR = 2). If i use these alarm states (1 or 2), it mismatch with the existing states (MajorLow =1, Nominal = 2).

How can I match the trap states [MAJOR, MINOR] with the actual alarm states[LOLO, LO, HIHI, HI, NOMINAL]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMP agents are dumb and will only send what you tell it to. You will have to modify how your Cisco device sends the traps by adjusting their severity if you can, or by mapping and reformatting the traps as they come into your NMS.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately I don't have privilege to modify the SNMP agent's dumb. So I managed, by getting the alarm severity state at the Trap Process which requires one more getRequest().